# How can I set priorities to quartz trigger?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler and there are 15 jobs. For each job there is one trigger.
I want to set priority for each trigger. I can set low priority as 10 and high priority as 1.
But as I am having 15 triggers for 15 jobs I need different priority for each trigger.
e.g trigger1 will have priority 10, trigger2 will have priority 9.
In this way I need to give same priority for two triggers.

So if two triggers with same priority will get execute at same time then which trigger will execute first?

Can anyone tell me how I can set different priorities for different triggers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggers have a 'priority' property on them.  Just set the property accordingly as the triggers are created, or use the api to retrieve the triggers, set the priorities, and reschedule them.

If two or more triggers have the same fire time and same priority, one will be randomly chosen for firing first (what else could the ordering be based on?).

Answer (score 13):

Trigger have a property called `WithPriority` which takes a integer value. When multiple triggers are fired at the same time the scheduler will fire the trigger with the highest priority first. And if the two triggers have same priority then either trigger will get fired.

- `.WithPriority(15)` will run first
- `.WithPriority(1)` will be the last trigger