# How can i prioritize pending jobs in Quartz that don't have same fire time?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Quartz has a nice feature of trigger priority which allows to order triggers with identical fire time. (This is [documented](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example14) and covered by a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941523/how-can-i-set-priorities-to-quartz-trigger) too).

How can I prioritize *all pending jobs*, not only those with identical fire time?

(I am fully aware this can lead to starvation of low priority jobs if higher-prioritized jobs keep coming in.)

Comment: Are you happy with this on production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this, however it looks possible to 'hack' without changing Quartz code.

It seems sufficient to override `RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers` (if using `RAMJobStore` of course) **properly** (e.g. call super implementation with big `maxCount`, reorder results on priority, `releaseAcquiredTrigger()` on all except first `originalMaxCount`).